# Taylor's series question on bounds

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, taylor-expansion

$f(x) = f(y) + f'(y)(x-y) + \frac{f"(y) (x-y)^2}{2} + ....$ is the taylor's series. I am aware of bounds which specify the error in approximating $f$ with a polynomial.

I want sufficient conditions for $f$ under which we have,
$f(x)  \ge f(y) + \alpha ||y-x||$, where $y$ is the argmin of $f$ and $\alpha >0$.

One way to look at this is : Because I know that for convex functions, $f(x)  \ge f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$, so if I can find sufficient conditions for a convex function for which $f'(y)(x-y) >0$ my question is answered.

Comment: In your  Taylor series It should be $ (x-y) ^k$  not $(y-x) ^k$! Have you seen what I mean?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal yes, thanks. bug corrected!

Comment: if $y$ is an interior point, you have $f'(y)=0$, convex or not. Are you sure that you are not looking for $f(x) \ge f(y) + \alpha \|x-y\|^2$? In that case a positive definite hessian at $y$ is sufficient.

Comment: @user251257 actually $f'(y)=0$ is not necessary if the minimization was over some set. Your second comment could be helpful, because if that condition is true then that implies that for some $\alpha$ my condition would be true too. Could you explain more on it?

Comment: @bissi like I said if $y$ is an interior point... Anyway check that $f'(y)d\ge 0$ holds for reasonable direction $d$ using the fact that $y$ is a minimizer. Reasonable depends on your feasible set and constraints.

Comment: @user251257 emmm, and how would i do that?

Comment: @bissi $f'(y)d = \lim_{t\to 0} (f(y+td) - f(y))/t$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37206/discussion-between-bissi-and-user251257).